# jQuery: Run function after other is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a function on site called like this:

```
function func1() {
    //some calculations
    $.ajax({
        success: function(data) {
            //here i'd like to put my function
        }
    });
}
```

I'd like to put my function in ajax call success using Tampermonkey or other userscript manager. Is it possible?

Comment: return the ajax promise from `func1`

Comment: I can't. func1() is created by site, func2() is function created by me using tampermonkey

Comment: then I think you are out of luck... except may be to use a timer like setTimeout() or using a Mutation Observer to observe the dom

Comment: @SebastianSzczepański, if you were able to put func2() why can't you re-write func1() using Tampermonkey?

Comment: @Arvind can i overwrite function with Ajax inside?